# Minimizing JS getter/setter boilerplate

Tags: javascript, closures, encapsulation, getter-setter

I am doing closure-oriented object creation with an object that has substantial boilerplate around getter/setter methods.  Is there any way to declare these properties as getter/setters without so much repetition?

Currently I have:

```
var test = function(){
    var width = 10;    
    var height = 10;    
    return {
        width: {get: function(){return width;}, set: function(_){width=_;}},
        height: {get: function(){return height;}, set: function(_){height=_;}},
    }
}
```

but I want something more like:

```
var test = function(){
    var width = 10;    
    var height = 10;    
    return {
        width: getset(width)
        height: getset(height),
    }
}
```

I want to write a function like:

```
var test = function(){

    var getset = function(val){
        return {
            get: function(){
                console.log('getting');
                return val
            },
            set: function(_){
                console.log('besetted');
                param=_
            },
        }
    }
    var width = 10;    
    var height = 10;    

    return {
        width: getset(width),
        height: getset(height),
    }
}
```

but this does not work; variables are not overridden properly.  What is the best way?  Is there a language feature for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var test = function(){

    var getset = function(value){
        var val = value;
        return {
            get: function(){
                console.log('getting');
                return val
            },
            set: function(_){
                console.log('besetted');
                val=_
            },
        }
    }
    var width = 10;
    var height = 10;

    return {
        width: getset(width),
        height: getset(height),
    }
}
```

A thing to remember with closures - You need a variable that is accessible throughout the scope inside your inner function as well as outside it.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is this:

```
var test = function()
{
    var
        width = 10,
        height = 10;

    this.setWidth = function(_w)
    {
        width = _w;
    };

    this.getWidth = function()
    {
        return width;
    };

    // etc.
}
```

Now you have a "class" which you can instantiate:

```
var testObj = new test();
console.log(testObj.getWidth()); // 10
testObj.setWidth(20);
console.log(testObj.getWidth()); // 20
```

Explaination: JS doesn't have "private" or "public" properties/methods. Instead, public object properties/methods are attached to `this`, while private "properties" are declared as function variables, as seen above.

Due to the *[closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29)* logic of JS, the function variables are always accessible for class methods, while they cannot be seen by other components.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
function GetSet(value) = {
  this.myValue = value;
  var that = this;

  this.getset = function(setter){
    if (setter === undefined){
      return that.myValue;
    } else {
      that.myValue = setter;
    }
  }
}
```

So you replace:

```
return {
    width: getset(width),
    height: getset(height),
}
```

With:

```
return {
  width: new GetSet(width),
  height: new GetSet(height)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ... variables are not overridden properly. ... Is there a language feature for this?

The language itself does not directly provide features. But one, as always, can make use of various function based patterns, like closures as poor man's helper and factory modules.

I personally, for reasons of code reuse, would modularize a helper function that generically solves creation of key-value-configuration based getters and setters.
Then one is free of just being focused on implementing the factory/constructor that has to solve the main task.

Besides mostly doubting architectures that sometimes paranoiac try to encapsulate every objects state for no good reason I hereby do provide a conceptual solution to it ... `[paranoid]`, `[Paranoiac]`, kind of *`test`* ...

```
var paranoid = (function () {


  var
    module,


    firstCharToUpperCase = function (str) {
      var
        list = str.split(""),
        char = list.shift()
      ;
      list.unshift(char.toUpperCase());

      return list.join("");
    },
    createKeyForSetter = function (key) {
      return ["set", firstCharToUpperCase(key)].join("");
    },
    createKeyForGetter = function (key) {
      return ["get", firstCharToUpperCase(key)].join("");
    },


    setTargetValue = function (target, key, value) {
      return (target[key] = value);
    },
    getTargetValue = function (target, key) {
      return target[key];
    },


    createAndAggregateGetterAndSetterForEachKeyValueAndTarget = function (collector, key) {

      collector.target[createKeyForSetter(key)] = function (value) {

      //return setTargetValue(collector.config, key, value);
        setTargetValue(collector.config, key, value);

      //return collector.target;
        return this;
      };
      collector.target[createKeyForGetter(key)] = function () {

        return getTargetValue(collector.config, key);
      };

      return collector;
    }
  ;


  module = {
    aggregateGettersAndSetters: createAndAggregateGetterAndSetterForEachKeyValueAndTarget
  };


  return module;


}());
```

...

```
var Paranoiac = (function (global) {


  var
    Constructor,
    factory,


    object_keys = global.Object.keys,


    createAndAggregateGetterAndSetterForEachKeyValueAndTarget = global.paranoid.aggregateGettersAndSetters,


    createInstanceFromConfig = function (config) {
      var instance = null;
      if ((config != null) && (object_keys(config).length >= 1))  {

        instance = new Constructor(config);
      }
      return instance;
    },
    isInstance = function (type) {
      return (
           (type != null)
        && (type instanceof Constructor)
      );
    }
  ;


  Constructor = function Paranoiac (config) {
    var
      instance = this
    ;
    object_keys(config).reduce(createAndAggregateGetterAndSetterForEachKeyValueAndTarget, {

      config: config,
      target: instance
    });
    return instance;
  };


  factory = {
    create      : createInstanceFromConfig,
    isParanoiac : isInstance
  };


  return factory;


}(window || this));
```

...

```
var
  p1 = Paranoiac.create({width: 55, height: 66}),
  p2 = Paranoiac.create({width: 44, height: 77}),
  p3 = Paranoiac.create({width: 33, height: 99})
;
console.log("Object.keys(p1) - ", Object.keys(p1));
console.log("Object.keys(p2) - ", Object.keys(p2));
console.log("Object.keys(p3) - ", Object.keys(p3));

console.log("p1.getWidth(), p1.getHeight() - ", [p1.getWidth(), p1.getHeight()]);
console.log("p2.getWidth(), p2.getHeight() - ", [p2.getWidth(), p2.getHeight()]);
console.log("p3.getWidth(), p3.getHeight() - ", [p3.getWidth(), p3.getHeight()]);

console.log('p1.setWidth("5"), p1.setHeight("6") - ', [p1.setWidth("5"), p1.setHeight("6")]);

console.log("p1.getWidth(), p1.getHeight() - ", [p1.getWidth(), p1.getHeight()]);
console.log("p2.getWidth(), p2.getHeight() - ", [p2.getWidth(), p2.getHeight()]);
console.log("p3.getWidth(), p3.getHeight() - ", [p3.getWidth(), p3.getHeight()]);

console.log('p2.setWidth("4"), p2.setHeight("7") - ', [p2.setWidth("4"), p2.setHeight("7")]);
console.log('p3.setWidth("3"), p3.setHeight("9") - ', [p3.setWidth("3"), p3.setHeight("9")]);

console.log("p1.getWidth(), p1.getHeight() - ", [p1.getWidth(), p1.getHeight()]);
console.log("p2.getWidth(), p2.getHeight() - ", [p2.getWidth(), p2.getHeight()]);
console.log("p3.getWidth(), p3.getHeight() - ", [p3.getWidth(), p3.getHeight()]);

console.log("Paranoiac.isParanoiac(p1) - ", Paranoiac.isParanoiac(p1));
console.log("Paranoiac.isParanoiac(p2) - ", Paranoiac.isParanoiac(p2));
console.log("Paranoiac.isParanoiac(p3) - ", Paranoiac.isParanoiac(p3));

console.log("Paranoiac.isParanoiac() - ", Paranoiac.isParanoiac());
console.log("Paranoiac.isParanoiac({}) - ", Paranoiac.isParanoiac({}));
```